# Sorting a matrix after embed function R

Tags: r, sorting, matrix, embed

So it was that simple, thank you.

I can't think of a general function that could help me sort the resulting matrix of the embed function.

ex:

```
moustache <- embed(c(1:4),3)
    moustache
          [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    3    2    1
    [2,]    4    3    2  

I would rather like the matrix :
          [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    1    2    3
    [2,]    2    3    4
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is unclear, what your sorting rule actually is. Maybe you want `moustache[,order(moustache[1,])]`.

Comment: Well embed gives me a reverse time series and I just want to put it back in its original order

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with standard indexing:

```
embed(1:4,3)[,3:1]
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4
```

Answer (score 1):

reverse the columns:

```
moustache[ , ncol(moustache):1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work to sort any matrix :

```
t(apply(moustache,1,sort))
```